# Displaying an image via PHP if HTML contains a specific word/phrase

Tags: php, strpos

I thought this would have been simple enough using strpos, so I must be oblivious to a horribly obvious mistake. I have this code here:

```
<div class="text" style="text-align:center;border:2px solid #bbb;font-size:12px;padding:0.2%;">
    <?php
        $root = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
        include "$root/scripts/display.php";
    ?>
</div>
```

Within the included file is a simple array that displays a random string from it:

```
$data=array("random string","something","something else","and so on");
$info=$data[rand(0,count($data)-1)];
echo $info;
```

What I want to do is to display an image that is relevant to a few of the random strings that are echoed. I thought I could do this with an if check for strpos as, for example "random" in $info, such that:

```
...
    ?>
</div>
<?php if(strpos($info,"random") !== false){?>
    <img src=...>
<?php } ?>
```

Problem is, this displays the image, even if "random" was not echoed.

I have a feeling this might have something to do with $info being checked, right?

Comment: That conditional looks fine, there must be some other issue.

Comment: I'll have to dig through my other codes, then. I'll see what I can come up with later in the day.

Answer (score 1):

can you please check with the following if it solves you problem

```
$data=array("1","2","3","4","5");
   $info = array_rand($data, count($data));
   print_r($info);

    <?php if(in_array("4", $info)){?>
        <img src=...>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Maybe you could also explain or add a link of what `in_array()` does.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is wrong. $info is not an array, but a string.

Comment: I made an edit to my question. I think it was confusing because I'm trying to look for a specific word in something that is output by the randomiser, not the entire output itself.

Comment: you can have a look at http://us3.php.net/in_array. If you do not understand then I will tell you